# Extract text from Website with Cordova

Tags: cordova, web-scraping, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a mobile application and I would like to extract a text value from a website which is not mine using Cordova, I googled but I could not find a valid example. Is there a plugin to do that?

I could not do this with Ajax because of the access orgin policy .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible approaches:**

- Use the **inAppbrowser** to load the page and run your script in that page to extract elements required using cross-browser communication. Read this [article](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser) which explains how to do it.
- Load the page in ajax call and parse the response based on markers using regex or convert the response to a HTML tag using this [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) and query DOM via JS API. Read this interesting [article](https://gonehybrid.com/a-little-bit-of-web-scraping-in-a-hybrid-mobile-app/) on web scraping in Hybrid app explained by [Ashteya Biharisingh](https://gonehybrid.com/author/ashteya/)
- Use the library [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) which runs on Node.js server. By using this lib you can load the web page inside a NodeJS environment and extract the dom parts using popular Jquery API. This requires a intermediate server and off load the scraping logic.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this approach is going to be practical because of the issue with CORS that you mentioned.

Your best bet would be to create your own API or microservice to scrape and expose that data for consumption by your Cordova app. This also makes it easy to cache the data if necessary.

Comment: I tried to use my server to scrape that data but the external domain change the value according to the IP and that would not work for each user.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of an unusual use case. If the third party site has an API you can use to get that data, that would be ideal. Otherwise scraping the site is likely to be the only way to achieve it.

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? It might help if I knew more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: The website is giving a streaming link based on IP and I want to get that link from the website and put it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need [Cordova whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/). As you can see on the bottom of the page, for AJAX and other requests, you will need the following meta tag

```html
<!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media, etc) except that 
    * CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
    * scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```